Is it possible to obtain the sequences from polyclonal antibody protein mixture via mass spec?
We have been using pAbs from an immunized goat for quite a few years but now the goat died. We only have the antigen affinity purified pAb proteins. Is it possible to obtain the sequences?
We have immunized several other goats, the resulting pAbs performed far worse than the one 'golden goat' produced. We are desperate ...
Thank you.

It appears that sequencing polyclonal antibody pools is a difficult thing to do de novo because of some technical limitations in terms of recovery of the specific high-affinity antibody/antibodies within the polyclonal pool that you are trying to find.
I'm no expert at all, but I did a simple search and came up with  the following paper for detecting polyclonal antibodies from SARS-CoV-2 vaccinated persons:

Le Bihan, T., Nunez de Villavicencio Diaz, T., Reitzel, C. et al. De novo protein sequencing of antibodies for identification of neutralizing antibodies in human plasma post SARS-CoV-2 vaccination. Nat Commun 15, 8790 (2024). https://doi.org/10.1038/s41467-024-53105-8

They looked at identification of antibodies and came to the conclusion that it was best and easiest to use B-cell sequencing along with protein sequencing. However, you don't have this opportunity because you only have purified IgG.
They identified 5 interesting papers (refs 20-24 in the reference section):

Frank A, Pevzner P. PepNovo: de novo peptide sequencing via probabilistic network modeling. Anal Chem. 2005 Feb 15;77(4):964-73. doi: 10.1021/ac048788h. PMID: 15858974.

Ma B, Zhang K, Hendrie C, Liang C, Li M, Doherty-Kirby A, Lajoie G. PEAKS: powerful software for peptide de novo sequencing by tandem mass spectrometry. Rapid Commun Mass Spectrom. 2003;17(20):2337-42. doi: 10.1002/rcm.1196. PMID: 14558135.

Liu K, Ye Y, Li S, Tang H. Accurate de novo peptide sequencing using fully convolutional neural networks. Nat Commun. 2023 Dec 2;14(1):7974. doi: 10.1038/s41467-023-43010-x. PMID: 38042873; PMCID: PMC10693636.

Eloff, K. et al. De novo peptide sequencing with InstaNovo: accurate, database-free peptide identification for large scale proteomics experiments. Preprint at bioRxiv https://doi.org/10.1101/2023.08.30.555055.

Yilmaz, M., Fondrie, W. E., Bittremieux, W., Oh, S. & Noble, W. S. De novo mass spectrometry peptide sequencing with a transformer model. 39th Int. Confer. Mach. Learn. 162, 25514–25522 (2022).


As you can see from the titles, most of these use some sort of machine learning/"AI" to help the sequencing identification. You would need to talk to your protein sequencing facility to see if they are capable of doing this, or perhaps get a grant to collaborate with a specialist group to do this work.
Reference 28 in the paper is also interesting:

Bondt, A. et al. Into the dark serum proteome: personalized features of IgG1 and IgA1 repertoires in severe COVID-19 patients. Mol. Cell Proteomics 23. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.mcpro.2023.100690 (2023).

A look at the "Cited By" section in the PubMed page for each article might be of use to you for more relevant references.
You might also have an advantage in having the lesser affinity goat sera, which you could potentially use for comparison of the antisera after sequencing to look for differences.
However, the high affinity ones might not also be high abundance, and I suspect that the work involved is a whole (potentially expensive) research project in itself for only one reagent, as you would need to generate each identified antibody and compare affinity to your protein target.

Thank you Bob! This is very helpful. The first paper you mentioned claims that they obtained some functional antibody sequences without using the RNA seq info, which could be useful in my situation. I will reach out to the group and see if they can help me! Thanks again for sharing this!

@JohnTran No problem. Looks like an interesting topic. At first glance I would have thought a trivial problem, so was surprised to find the complexity. Note how recent all those papers are, right at the cutting edge of technology at the moment it would seem.

I want to report back as I have reached out to the group behind this paper https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-024-53105-8.
They said they have done similar projects in the past to convert goat pAbs to mAbs. This is a case study they shared with me. https://www.rapidnovor.com/sequencing-recombinant-goat-polyclonal-antibodies/. They offer this as a commercial service (huge surprise to me, most people including myself did not think this is possible). I will have to get the budget approved, but I feel hopeful.
